# iPhone - recognizing a wave form/frequency

Tags: iphone, audio

I capture a sound using my App. Suppose this sound is a sinusoidal 1 KHz sound and there is a background sound present. How do I identify that this 1 KHz sound is present on the sound?

I mean, I can imagine how elements can be found in images, as for example, if you are looking for a yellow square on an image, all you have to do is to specify the color you want, give it a certain tolerance, and look for a group of pixels that have that color and form a square shape. But what about sounds? How do you identify a wave form and frequency when all you get is an amplitude value that represents 1/44.000 of the wave form in one second?

I don't want the code, as this is too complex for this post, but if you guys can point me on the right direction of how this is done, free source codes that can exemplify the techniques or the math behind it, I appreciate. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to do a FFT (Fast Fourrier Transform) of the wave to have the frequencies it is composed of. This is a classic task in signal processing (Fourrier Transforms are transformations to switch between time and frequency spaces) so you should find a lot of resources on the subject.

Maybe look at the CoreAudio framework and sample codes too.
(See also [CoreAudio overview](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/CoreAudioOverview/Introduction/Introduction.html) and the [Audio and Video topics](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/index.html#section=Topics&topic=Audio%20&%20Video) in Apple's doc)

Comment: Also look at the Accelerate framework, which has numerous hardware-accelerated FFT functions like `vDSP_fft_zrip'